# JTree, always display all nodes in "edit mode"

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm displaying a tree of custom objects, and I've got custom custom `CellTreeEditor` and `CellTreeRenderer` set.

Now what I really want is to always display all objects as in "edit mode". Right now I have the `CellTreeRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent()` and `CellTreeEditor.getTreeCellEditorComponent()` implemented almost identically. This kind of works, but I still have to click a node to focus it before I can do any editing.

Is there any more sensible way of doing this, perhaps like saying no renderer should never be used, defaulting to my `CellTreeEditor`?

******UPDATE****

To clearify: What I have is a tree looking like this (and yes, it also looks like crap, but that's beside the point):

[image: JTree showing renderer and editor components]

Right now, I accomplish this by having a renderer and an editor that returns identical components from `getTreeCell[Renderer|Editor]Component()`.

If I click on the down-arrow on the ComboBox supplied by the renderer, it will flicker slighty as it opens the dropdown, but then be interrupted and replaced by my editor component. This means I have to click it again to open the dropdown. This is the behaviour I want to avoid.

Comment: no, you don't want to have your editor shared across cells (nasty thingies start to happen) Instead, add a TreeCellListener which listens for changes in the lead (aka: focused) selection path and then explicitly start editing on that path

Comment: forgetting the flicker for now (that's probably due to a slight mis-alignment of renderer vs. editor) you basically have to grab the mouseEvent that starts the editor, check if it is inside the button and if so programmatically show the dropdown once the editor has been added to the hierarchy - easier said than done, I know :) How about showing an sscce including your custom renderer/editor so we try to get it there?

Answer (score 4):

Expanding my comment: no, you don't want to have your editor shared across cells (nasty thingies start to happen) Instead, add a TreeCellListener which listens for changes in the lead (aka: focused) selection path and then explicitly start editing on that path

```
    final JXTree tree = new JXTree();
    tree.setEditable(true);
    tree.expandAll();
    TreeSelectionListener l = new TreeSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
            final TreePath path = e.getNewLeadSelectionPath();
            if (path != null) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tree.startEditingAtPath(path);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    };
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(l);
```

The trick to really make it work is the usual: wrap the custom reaction into an invokeLater to be sure the tree's internal update is complete

Comment: Forgive me for my probably stupid question. but: My nodes automatically goes into edit mode when I click on a node, without me having done anything more than setting a custom CellEditor on it. What additional value is this supposed to give?

Comment: ehh ... you don't have to _click_ on the node ... ? Maybe I misunderstood your question, elaborate a bit on what exactly you want to _achieve_ (not on the problems you might have with a solution :-)

Comment: I was just asking because I'm assuming I was too _stoopid_ to understand your answer. It might have been genious, and just what I needed. 8) Anyway, updated the question now. Hope this makes it clearer!