# How do I set a JTree to always display using its cell editors?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree

```
JTree tree = new JTree();
tree.setCellRenderer(// ...);
tree.setCellEditor(// ...);
tree.setEditable(true);
```

that uses its cell renderer to display its cells; if the cells are clicked, then they use the cell editor to display. Is there a way I can *only* display using the cell editor?

1. I have tried to just remove the renderer. This doesn't work because the JTree resorts to its default cell renderer.
2. This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604095/jtree-always-display-all-nodes-in-edit-mode), however, that question doesn't seem to contain an answer pertinent to my specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to create a TreeCellRenderer that returns the associated TreeCellEditor component.

Try something like this:

```
        tree.setCellRenderer(new TreeCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(
                JTree tree, Object value, 
                boolean selected, boolean expanded,
                boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            return tree.getCellEditor().getTreeCellEditorComponent(tree, value, 
                                                      selected, expanded, leaf, row);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with cell editors and renderers is that one GUI component is supposed to be re-used to draw every one of the elements in the list (renderer) and only a single line can be edited at a time (editor). If you break that single GUI component rule, Swing GUIs can behave awkwardly, slowly or even completely break.

In other words, using an editing component (like a dropdiwn) for the cell renderer you will run into problems, because the same JComboBox should be used for each of your list's elements. If you create a different renderer object for each tree element, you'll run into memory problems and other unusual behavior

If you really want to use a dropdown for the renderer, you can do it by implementing a TreeCellRenderer yourself that returns a unique JComboBox instance when `public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus)` is called.